# Open3d: How do I create an icosphere/geodesic polyhedron sphere?

Tags: computer-vision, open3d

I tried to create an icosphere in open3d. I tried the "create_sphere" function within TriangleMesh, but for some reason the mesh is made out of rectangles rather than triangles:

```
import open3d as o3d
a = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere()
a.compute_vertex_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([a])
```

As you can see, the sphere is not made of triangles. How do I generate an icosphere of triangles?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see, the sphere is not made of triangles.

**Not true**. The sphere **is** made of triangles.

---

As stated in the Open3D [documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere), `open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_sphere` returns `open3d.geometry.TriangleMesh`, hence it must be made of triangles.

To access the data, use `np.asarray(a.triangles)`.

---

Also notice that you can press `w` when the visualizer is on. And you shall see wireframes like this:
[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't press w. Thanks